# Create a column that has the same length of the longest column in the data at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data:

```
data = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]
dataFrame = pandas.DataFrame(data).transpose()
```

Output:

```
     0    1    2
0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  2.0  2.0  2.0
2  3.0  3.0  3.0
3  NaN  4.0  4.0
4  NaN  5.0  5.0
5  NaN  NaN  6.0
6  NaN  NaN  7.0
```

Is it possible to create a 4th column AT THE SAME TIME the others columns are created in data, which has the same length as the longest column of this dataframe (3rd one)?

The data of this column doesn't matter. Assume it's 8. So this is the desired output can be:

```
     0    1    2    3
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  8.0
1  2.0  2.0  2.0  8.0
2  3.0  3.0  3.0  8.0
3  NaN  4.0  4.0  8.0
4  NaN  5.0  5.0  8.0
5  NaN  NaN  6.0  8.0
6  NaN  NaN  7.0  8.0
```

In my script the dataframe keeps changing every time. This means the longest columns keeps changing with it.

Thanks for reading

Comment: What if there is a `NaN` value in `column 2` the length should be 7 or 6 in this case?

Comment: The length should be 6. I didn't even think of that. Thank you

Comment: Why do you want it created at the same time? What's the issue of an additional statement?

Comment: I'ts really complicated. I would have to give you details about the project. It's just not an option.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not going to be possible. Or you do this by adding the column to `data` in the first place. After, it's too late! you already have your DataFrame.

Comment: I don't understand why it is so important that the column exists at the time df is created and not added in after. This does not make sense to me, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is quite similar to answers from @jpp, @Cleb, and maybe some other answers here, just slightly simpler:

```
data = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]] + [[]]
```

This will automatically give you a column of NaNs that is the same length as the longest columnn, so you don't need the extra work of calculating the length of the longest column.  Resulting dataframe:

```
     0    1    2   3
0  1.0  1.0  1.0 NaN
1  2.0  2.0  2.0 NaN
2  3.0  3.0  3.0 NaN
3  NaN  4.0  4.0 NaN
4  NaN  5.0  5.0 NaN
5  NaN  NaN  6.0 NaN
6  NaN  NaN  7.0 NaN
```

Note that this answer is less general than some others here (such as by @jpp & @Cleb) in that it will only fill with NaNs.  If you want some default fill values other than NaN, you should use one of their answers.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can append to a list which then immediately feeds the `pd.DataFrame` constructor:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data + [[8]*max(map(len, data))]).transpose()

print(df)

     0    1    2    3
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  8.0
1  2.0  2.0  2.0  8.0
2  3.0  3.0  3.0  8.0
3  NaN  4.0  4.0  8.0
4  NaN  5.0  5.0  8.0
5  NaN  NaN  6.0  8.0
6  NaN  NaN  7.0  8.0
```

But this is inefficient. Pandas uses NumPy to hold underlying series and setting a series to a constant value is trivial and efficient; you can simply use:

```
df[3] = 8
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not entirely clear what you mean by *at the same time*, but the following would work:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]
# get the longest list in data
data.append([8] * max(map(len, data)))
pd.DataFrame(data).transpose()
```

yielding

```
     0    1    2    3
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  8.0
1  2.0  2.0  2.0  8.0
2  3.0  3.0  3.0  8.0
3  NaN  4.0  4.0  8.0
4  NaN  5.0  5.0  8.0
5  NaN  NaN  6.0  8.0
6  NaN  NaN  7.0  8.0
```

Comment: At the same time `data` variable is created./At the same time the other columns are created

Comment: @jxpython: Not sure how this can possibly look like as one either has to manipulate `data` before the dataframe is created (as I did) or manipulate the dataframe afterwards (as in the other answers). At least i currently don't see another option as at some point one has to find the longest sublist...

Comment: @JohnE: Thanks, yes, this would be another option. Just see that that jpp expressed above's solution in a single line (should have done this too :) ), and I guess that comes closest to what is described in the question. But without further feedback by OP, it is difficult to improve the existing answers (you could add yours as well!?).

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll go ahead and add mine altho it's not substantially different than yours or @jpp's (just slightly simpler)

Comment: @JohnE: Only issue there is, that one would still need an extra step to fill in a value (here: `8`).

Comment: @Cleb  OP said the data doesn't matter so I was assuming `NaN` was as good for fill as `8` (but maybe he wanted some number rather than NaN), but of course you are correct that it would require another step to fill with 8s rather than NaNs.  (I'll add output to my answer so it's more obvious that it's filled with NaNs instead of 8s.)

Comment: @JohnE: Correct, OP needs to specify further; I like the solution (also upvoted). We'll see whether there will be any additional feedback at some point :)

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to do it as you create the DataFrame, simply chain a call to `assign`:

```
pd.DataFrame(data).T.assign(**{'3': 8})
```

```
     0    1    2  3
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  8
1  2.0  2.0  2.0  8
2  3.0  3.0  3.0  8
3  NaN  4.0  4.0  8
4  NaN  5.0  5.0  8
5  NaN  NaN  6.0  8
6  NaN  NaN  7.0  8
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this does not create the new column at the same time the first three are created.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `def` (read comments):

```
def f(df):
   l=[8]*df[max(df,key=lambda x:df[x].count())].count()
   df[3]=l+[np.nan]*(len(df)-len(l))
   # the above two lines can be just `df[3] = another solution currently for this problem`
   return df
dataFrame = f(pandas.DataFrame(data).transpose())
```

Then now:

```
print(dataFrame)
```

Returns:

```
     0    1    2  3
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  8
1  2.0  2.0  2.0  8
2  3.0  3.0  3.0  8
3  NaN  4.0  4.0  8
4  NaN  5.0  5.0  8
5  NaN  NaN  6.0  8
6  NaN  NaN  7.0  8
```

Answer (score 0):

If at you mean at the same time as running `pd.DataFrame`, the data has to be prepped before it is loaded to your frame.

```
data = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]

longest = max(len(i) for i in data)
dummy = [8 for i in range(longest)] #dummy data filled with 8
data.append(dummy)

dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data).transpose()
```

The example above gets the longest element in your list and creates a dummy to be added onto it before creating your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add an element to the list that is passed to the dataframe:

```
 pd.DataFrame(data + [[np.hstack(data).max() + 1] * len(max(data))]).T

     0    1    2    3
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  8.0
1  2.0  2.0  2.0  8.0
2  3.0  3.0  3.0  8.0
3  NaN  4.0  4.0  8.0
4  NaN  5.0  5.0  8.0
5  NaN  NaN  6.0  8.0
6  NaN  NaN  7.0  8.0
```

If data is to be modified just:

```
data = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]
data = data + [[np.hstack(data).max() + 1] * len(max(data))]

pd.DataFrame(data).T
```